# Set Mailbox resulting to Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'

Tags: powershell, outlook, office365

I'm trying to edit a simple script to enable email forwarding in O365. The user's email and email to forward to are listed on a CSV file. The CSV file has two headers named Main_email and Lead_email.

```
Import-Module MSOnline

$emails = Import-CSV "C:\Powershell\leaverforwarding.csv"

ForEach($mail in $emails)
{

Set-Mailbox -Identity $mail.Main_email -ForwardingSmtpAddress $mail.Lead_email -DeliverToMailboxAndForward $true 

}
```

```
Write-ErrorMessage : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "" to type
"Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter". Error: "Parameter values of type
Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter can't be empty. Specify a value, and try again.
Parameter name: identity"
At C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpEXO_0bsfw4hc.ssg\tmpEXO_0bsfw4hc.ssg.psm1:1120 char:13
+             Write-ErrorMessage $ErrorObject
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-Mailbox], ParameterTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=DS0PR12MB6485,RequestId=6af035e1-07e3-260e-b452-93ab37192b14,TimeStamp=Wed, 19 A
   pr 2023 16:42:21 GMT],Write-ErrorMessage
```

To some extent, the script is working because it actually enables and add the forwarding, but I kept on getting the errors below afterwards and I can't find a way to remove it nor if its doing other changes that I'm unaware of.  I am just starting my way around Powershell to make things more efficient with my O365 tasks. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Do you have empty cells or empty lines in your CSV file?

Comment: Are the fields in your csv separated by a **comma** ? If not you need to specify the character used with parameter `-Delimiter` on the Import-Csv cmdlet